# Consequences of Nash-Tognoli Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

The Nash-Tognoli theorem states that every closed and smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to a real algebraic variety. This appears to me as a very strong and surprising fact.
However, I am not aware of any consequences, yet I have also been almost completely ignorant towards real algebraic geometry.

**Question**: What are nice consequences of the Nash-Tognoli theorem?

Answer (score 7):

I do not know about "nice" (which is a matter of taste) but one can prove (using the N-T theorem) that if $M$ is a smooth closed manifold, then there exists a polygonal linkage $L$ such that the moduli space $M(L)$ of planar realizations of $L$ has a component diffeomorphic to $M$. Bill Thurston named it "an airplane theorem." See

*Kapovich, Michael; Millson, John J.*, [**Universality theorems for configuration spaces of planar linkages**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(01)00034-9), Topology 41, No. 6, 1051-1107 (2002). [ZBL1056.14077](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1056.14077).

Comment: Why "an airplane theorem"? Why "airplane"? I don't see the connection... Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Imagine you are flying in an airplane (as a passenger!) and you have a conversation with a person occupying a seat next to you. At some point, your neighbor asks you "What do you do for living?" You answer, "I am a mathematician, a topologist." The natural responce is something like "what's that?" or even "you mean a topographer?" What could you tell them? Thurston's answer would be along the lines "Let me give you an example. For instance, I can show how to build a bar-and-joint mechanism that can forge your signature." That's why it's an "airplane theorem."

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Incidentally, [Zach Abel](http://zacharyabel.com/) proved in his Ph.D. thesis that the linkage can be truly planar in that bars do not cross one another.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Thank you for reminding me the name!

Answer (score 6):

While not relying on Nash-Tognoli, that theorem makes something like the [Brieskorn spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Brieskorn_spheres) inevitable. Though it is still surprising how simple are the polynomials that cut out exotic $S^7$'s in $\mathbb{C}^5$.

Comment: There are also similarly simple polynomials in 5 variables which cut out nonsmoothable PL manifolds, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408221/the-easiest-non-smoothable-manifold?rq=1).